# How to use remote server's database?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I want to insert `username`, `filename` and `Hex_format` into remote server's SQLite database:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
import urllib
import urllib2
import paramiko
import sqlite3

username = "e100075"
filename = "screenshot.png"
Hex_format = "FSGDSFDSSFGRSSCD"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('hostname', username="username", password="password") 

print "Connect to server...."

try:
    db = sqlite3.connect('screenshoter.db')
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userid TEXT, activity_id TEXT, date_time TEXT, screenshot_filename TEXT, screenshot_md5 TEXT, 
                      num_clicks INT, num_of_mouse_movements INT, num_pause INT );''')
    cursor.execute("insert into users (userid,screenshot_filename,screenshot_md5) values (?, ?, ?)",(username, filename, Hex_format))
    db.commit()
except Exception as e:
    db.rollback()
    raise e
finally:
    db.close()
ssh.close()
```

It's saved in my local database instead. How can I do this?

Comment: You could load the DB via scp or as a remote file on your local filesystem. However, this is not a common usage of sqlite (see http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5)

Comment: SQLite is not intended as a remote database, there is no server. To use it via SSH you'd have to pipe commands via the `sqlite` shell, or create your own proxy server. It would probably be easier to execute the code on the remote server, or to run a real SQL server.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def sql(sql):
    try:
        ssh = SSHClient()
        #ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        ssh.connect(hostname='ip', username='user', password='pass')
        sleep(0.5)
        stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(sql)
        result = stdout.readlines()
        print(result)
        if not result:
            rows = stderr.readlines()
            print(rows)
        ssh.close()
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What is `sql` intended to be?

Comment: sql = your sql command
sql("select * from table;")

Comment: `sql` is being sent to a shell. It has to be a shell command.